# Spark: GenericMutableRow cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte and <none> is not a term

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to store data from a Spark (v.1.6) DataFrame to Cassandra. I managed to get the examples on the [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md) page running, however, I am stuck with my own code. Consider the following snippet:

```
case class MyCassandraRow(id : Long, sfl : Seq[Float])

df.map(r => 
   MyCassandraRow(
        r.getAsLong(0),
        r.getAs[MySeqFloatWrapper]("sfl").getSeq())
).saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table")
```

`MySeqFloatWrapper` is a UDT, I wrote, which has a method `getSeq()` and returns a `Seq[Float]`.

Unfortunately, if I run this code, I get a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte
```

Actually, I get this exception even if I do (and also if I do `Row(r.getLong(0))`), but not if I write:

```
df.map(r => r.getLong(0)).collect()
```

On the other hand, if I add a `Row` around my case class and I write

```
df.map(r => 
  Row(
   MyCassandraRow(
        r.getAsLong(0),
        r.getAs[MySeqFloatWrapper]("sfl").getSeq())
  )
).saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table")
```

I get the following exception:

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a term
```

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that the `ClassCastException` was related to my UDT `MySeqFloatWrapper` and the `sqlType` I defined there, which apparently was not considered so far as with Spark 1.5 it worked fine, but with Spark 1.6 no longer (see also [SPARK-12878](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12878)).

If you need a template to see how to define UDTs properly, see also the `VectorUDT` example on [github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.scala).